# Select radio button in loop with index

Tags: html, pandas, button, flask, jinja2

I have a template where I am passing a pandas dataframe and looping through each row to create columnar entries. I have successfully created inline radio button forms for each row.

My issue is in the radio buttons. I want to select a certain radio button, say 'Match', and when I click submit it will return 'You selected Match'. But I am getting the same message for all entries/rows in the loop, not for the specific row in which I selected the 'Match' radio button. I need to get an index based submission of radio buttons. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT1:** I've tried running this code to somehow link the form by the index of the loop, but I keep getting a `KeyError: options0` error (replacing the index value with the row index).

**app.py code:**

```
@app.route('/',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def home():
    options = ''
    x = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')

    if request.method == 'POST':
    for i in range(x.count()[0]):
        if request.form['options'+str(i)] == 'match':
            options = 'You selected Match'
        elif request.form['options'+str(i)] == 'notMatch':
            options = 'You selected Not Match'
        else:
            options = 'You selected IDK'

    return render_template('index.html', data=x, options=options)
```

**html code:**

```
{% for index,row in data.iterrows() %}

... Other code ...

<form action="" method="post">
  <div class="col">

      <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="options{{index}}" value="match">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="match">Match</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="options{{index}}" value="notMatch">
          <label class="form-check-label" for="notMatch">Not Match</label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
              <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="options{{index}}" value="idk">
              <label class="form-check-label" for="idk">IDK</label>
            </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="submit">Submit</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger"name="reset" value="reset">Reset</button>
  </div>
</form>
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT2:** After some fiddling around I located my problem to be in the app.py code. The index is passed properly from the html, and if I hardcode the index value the buttons work. But I'm unable to pass the corrected and incremented index value in the request call in an automated fashion, like:

```
for i in range(x.count()[0]):
    if requests.form['options{}'.format(i)] == 'match':
        options = 'You selected Match'
```

Comment: It looks like your for loop is just making the same form for the number of rows in your dataframe. You should try updating name of the radio input e.g. options1, options2, options2 for rows 1, 2, 3 etc.

Comment: @PGHE i've added my edits according to your suggestion above, and I can't figure out what's wrong

Comment: I tried this also, making sure to apply the same index call in the template and the python script, but I get an error: `werkzeug.exceptions.HTTPException.wrap.<locals>.newcls: 400 Bad Request: KeyError: 'options0'`. In fact, with the edits I added above, I get the same key for every radio button in every row, minus the first row in which all buttons give me `'options1'`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: after the two edits, I'm unsure what is the current state of your code / problem. But ISTM the solution is using `requests.form.get("options{}".format(i))` instead of using `[]` indexing. That way, if the key is not present in the form data (which is most of the time), you get back a `None` value instead of an exception.